# Сoncatenation FiizBuzz

Tags: javascript, string, function, numbers, palindrome

Create a function called “sum”, that takes two arguments: a number, represented as string, and a number. If an argument of type number is divisible by 3, 5 and 15 without remainder, multiply it by -1. Function should return numeric sum of two arguments.

My solution is not full, help to understand what should i do

```
const sum = (value1, value2) => {
   for(let i = 0; i < value1, value2; i++) {
     if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0 && i% 15 === 0) {
       return value1 + value2
     }
   }
    return;
  };
```

Examples:

`sum('25',15)` equals 10, because 15 is divisible by 3, 5 and 15 and therefore the sum is `25 + (-15)`
`sum('41',3)` equals 44, because neither 41 nor 3 are divisible by 3,5, nor 15 and the sum is `41 + 3`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `i < value1, value2` doesn't make sense

Comment: I want to create a function which returns me such examples
sum('25', 15) // 10
sum(41, '3') // 44
sum('3', 45) // -42
sum('15', 15) // 0

Comment: Why is `sum('15', 15)` equal to `0` (zero)? Shouldn't it be `-30`?

Comment: Because -15 + -15 equal zero i think so

Comment: (-15) + (-15) should equal (-30) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the expected output given:

```js
const sum = (value1, value2) => {
  var result = 0;
  const arr = [value1, value2];
  arr.forEach(function(value) {
    if ((typeof value === 'number') && value % 15 === 0) {
      result += value * (-1);
    } else result += Number(value);
  });
  return result;
}


console.log(sum('25', 15));
console.log(sum(41, '3'));
console.log(sum('3', 45));
console.log(sum('15', 15));
console.log(sum(3, 15));
```